# Error build Rust for linux in macos - Openssl

Tags: rust, build, openssl, rust-cargo, pkg-config

Trying to compile for linux from a mac throws this error, I have **openssl** and **pkg-config** installed from **brew**.

And in the file ~/.cargo/config I have this configuration.

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

**Error:**

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.72`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/Proyect/cvm/target/release/build/openssl-sys-66182f9fe15cdddc/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  run pkg_config fail: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"openssl\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1\nerror: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate\n\n--- stderr\nPackage openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'openssl' found\n"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-apple-darwin
  $TARGET = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  openssl-sys = 0.9.72

  ', /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.72/build/find_normal.rs:180:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL crate fails compilation on Mac OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612395/openssl-crate-fails-compilation-on-mac-os-x-10-11)

Comment: I tried all the answers in that thread but none of them worked for me, that's why I created this one :(.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426759/linker-errror-while-cross-compiling-for-android

Comment: FWIW, the target in your cargo config is x86_64-unknown-linux-musl, but the target in the error message is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu - https://github.com/rust-lang/rls/issues/250

Answer (score 9):

The error message contains three possible solutions:

First make sure it is really installed including for development (which is what you need if you want to compile code against openssl):

> Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
> For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

If it is already really installed, then it could not be found. This can be fixed by adding the directory containing `openssl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable:

> Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
> you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc' to the
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Or by setting the `OPENSSL_DIR` to point to where the openssl code is on your system:

> Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys`
> crate cannot proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed
> and this crate had trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR`
> environment variable for the compilation process.

Comment: I have done all those configurations but it keeps throwing me the same error, it is in the line openssl-sys-0.9.72/build/find_normal.rs:180:5, it gives me the impression that it needs some openssl that is precompiled for linux.

Comment: If you're cross-compiling, you need to install openssl-dev for the _target_ system, not the host system, and point `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to this _target_ install.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set/export these openssl (brew installed) directories on Mac trying to compile a AWS Lambda Rust function:

`export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl export OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

This is part of the error message I was getting to hopefully help the coders still using Google in 2023:

```
cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR unset
```

Answer (score -4):

try add

```bash
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

to your Cargo.toml