Cross compiling Rust app depending on ffmpeg fails
Trying to cross compile an application depending on ffmpeg-next from Linux to Windows. It works well on Linux but when using cross to compile for Windows I get this error
error: failed to run custom build command for `ffmpeg-sys-next v7.0.0`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/target/debug/build/ffmpeg-sys-next-a15fd7744c0ae4bc/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBAVUTIL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ffmpeg-sys-next-7.0.0/build.rs:740:14:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
pkg-config exited with status code 1
> PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil

The system library `libavutil` required by crate `ffmpeg-sys-next` was not found.
The file `libavutil.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.```

Appreciate the help.


maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/71327114/5600363 helps

It seems that in the Windows machine you don't have a specific C-lib, based on the message bellow.
The system library libavutil required by crate ffmpeg-sys-next was not found.
The file libavutil.pc needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.```
I had a similar problem a few months ago and had to install manually the absent C-lib. Try to search this lib with a package manager like winget and install it.
Another possibility is to check ffmpeg documentation and maybe install it locally.
